# How to incorporate user settings in an RSS feed?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, rss

I am looking to have RSS feeds which are dynamically generated (that I can do) but are based on user preference settings.  So for example if a user wanted to see in their RSS only pictures with certain tags, their RSS feed would show them.

There are two problems with what I am looking to do:

1. It cannot be a simple user-id based system, since some users may not be allowed access to certain items, so I do not want their feeds to show them. Using a user-id based system means someone can enter in random user numbers until they get one with things they should not be seeing.
2. Most RSS readers do not have the ability to use cookies, so the login data stored there would not work.

The system generating this is PHP & MySQL based.

What suggestions does everyone have for a secure system which can do this?

Comment: Are they running on a lan or the open internet. If it is lan, maybe you can use their ip to lock the feed to certain ip addresses?

Comment: Open internet, so IP locking is out, sadly.

Comment: If you can restrict _some users_ from _access to certain items_, you can do the same `user <=> access list` check before generating the actual RSS feed.

Answer (score 0):

If it is open to the internet then basically there is no way to secure the rss. Sad.

What you can do is have minimal (not critical) data be available on the rss, and do the standard sign in cookie stuff when then click on the rss link to get details.

Answer (score -1):

How about using `UUID` so that they are unique and also not easy for any user to randomly generate a valid `UUID` of your system?

Comment: Uuid is still guessable. Harder but guessable, if they try hard enough.

Comment: Good luck with guessing `UUID` :)

Comment: Firstly. Uuid is not a random string. It is based in the time and the machine generating it.

Comment: So based on that the number of combinations drop by a lot. It is not that hard to put together a wget script that test the combinations and report any that returns data in the rss feed.